# Ionic/AngularJS - How to troubleshoot error 'Unfortunately, <app name> has stopped.'

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, crash

If I exit my app (push home button then swipe to close) then turn off location service, I get the error

> "Unfortunately,  has stopped."

This is happening every time on Android, yet to check iOS. How can I go about troubleshooting this? Any ideas what it could be caused by?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the logs in studio when crash appears.
it helps in finding where is the crash and what causing it.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to view crash logs outside of android studio? I'm testing the app on a device using ionic run with livereload etc.